# SDWebImage - how to extend download timeout

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, timeout, sdwebimage, imagedownload

I'm using SDWebImage in my application and it works great on WiFi and 'good' 3G connections. However under slow network connections (e.g. poor 3G) it always fails downloading images because it looks like there's a 10 second timeout limit.

**Can I extend such timeout so that the download can take longer before failing?**

I could not find any 'timeout' property on the SDWebImage headers and I just found some hardcoded values such as

`NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest.alloc initWithURL:url cachePolicy:(options & SDWebImageDownloaderUseNSURLCache ? NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy : NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData) timeoutInterval:15];`

Before I used SDWebImage my low-end users were able to download images successfully (just by waiting a bit more), now the download always fails. (I'm using 'http://mschrag.github.io' to simulate slow network conditions)

Answer (score 3):

I submitted a change that added a `downloadTimeout` property to the `SDWebImageDownloader` class. [See pull request #591](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/pull/591). And it looks like, as of this writing, that the pull request was accepted and merged into 'master'. Hopefully that solves things for you.

Answer (score 1):

check it

```
SDWebImageManager *manager  = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
manager.imageDownloader.downloadTimeout = 60.0;
```

And add options

```
SDWebImageRetryFailed
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution for swift developer

```
SDWebImageDownloader.shared.config.downloadTimeout = 300
```

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Comment: sort answers is more effective rather than description. sort answer  is better than perfect answer above all answer is depreciated and I have so many effort to find this solution so i think it is use full for people